# What kind of question is this?

Tags: parts-of-speech

When someone asks a question strictly to impart knowledge, as in:

> Or do you presume on the riches of his kindness and forbearance and
>   patience, not knowing that God’s kindness is meant to lead you to
>   repentance? (‭Romans‬ ‭2‬:‭4‬ ESV)

What is the type of question called?

This might be a poor example but I'm **not** looking for "rhetorical question." While yes, this may not be asked to expect a response, I'm more looking for a word with a definition of something like this:

> A type of question asked to impart knowledge or grant clarity to a
>   subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can define it as an ***explanatory question***:

> - Explanatory questions help us understand the reality of a situation whether its a moral, religious, social or economic reality and explain it. They focus on what is or is supposed to be real and not what should be.

Comment: Please cite the source.